# StackSaga with Eureka client is failed with error - Service-to-service communication is failed [StackSaga Error Code: SS-0034]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, stacksaga

The properties file.

```
spring.application.name=user-service
server.port=0

management.server.port=2077
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

stacksaga.enable=true
stacksaga.transaction-id-prefix=us
stacksaga.app-release-version=1.0.0
stacksaga.component-scan=com.example


stacksaga.connect.admin-url=http://localhost:4444
stacksaga.connect.admin-username=user-service
stacksaga.connect.admin-password=mglMhRAHr1cEea83
```

```
2023-09-26 23:12:46.591 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:47.599 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:48.604 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:49.610 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:50.620 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:51.628 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:52.634 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:53.640 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:54.645 DEBUG [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] .InternalServiceCommunicationCoordinator : Internal service-communication validation URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate
2023-09-26 23:12:54.652 ERROR [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.config.ApplicationStartConfig  : Validation of service-to-service communication is failed.
2023-09-26 23:12:54.653  WARN [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is 
[StackSaga Error Code: SS-0034]
[See More: https://www.stacksaga.org/1.0.0/errors?errorCode=SS-0034]
[Message: Validation of service-to-service (internal) communication is failed. [URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate]]
org.stacksaga.exception.InternalCommunicationFailedException: Validation of service-to-service (internal) communication is failed. [URL : http://192.168.8.101:9354/actuator/stacksaga/validate]
2023-09-26 23:12:54.669  INFO [user-service,,] 21992 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `server.port` and `management.server.port` are different. if the management server is run on a different port you have to mention the port to the StackSaga. if you don't, StackSaga tires to the default web server port that was started.

Due to you are using the StackSaga client with the Eureka Client, you can configure it like below.

```
#The port should be the same as that used for the management server.
eureka.instance.metadata-map.stacksagaManagementPort=2077
```

Answer (score 0):

#The port should be the same as that used for the management server.
eureka.instance.metadata-map.stacksagaManagementPort=2077

Comment: I’m glad to hear you found an answer here on the Stack Overflow community, but please be sure to reserve the _Answers_ feature for actual answers. While I’m sure other contributors appreciate your gratitude, **the best way to express that gratitude is to upvote their answer**. You’ll need to gain some reputation here on Stack Overflow before you’re able to do that; you can do that by suggesting edits to answers or contributing useful posts to the community.